# Apache Camel Websocket reverse proxy?

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel, reverse-proxy

We have an app on Java + Spring boot + Apache camel, which runs as reverse proxy with request / response logic for SOAP and REST. I was asked to add weboskcet connections support. I'd like to know if there is an easy way to implement this behavior.

I tried using **org.apache.camel:camel-atmosphere-websocket** for client connection and **org.apache.camel:camel-ahc-ws** to connect to the server. But there are drawbacks:

1. What I got is not a proxy. More like: client - server+client - server. The app establishes permanent connection with the server, not on the flight. The server always thinks it has only one client.
   The connection is established via:

```
from("atmosphere-websocket:///proxy-ws")
// ...
  .to("ahc-ws://127.0.0.1:3000")

from("ahc-ws://127.0.0.1:3000")
// ...
  .to("atmosphere-websocket:///proxy-ws")
```

2. I keep getting an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to send message to single connection; connection key is not set.

That's because backward route doesn't know exactly which client should receive the message